# operator++ postfix is not declared

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the line

`while (prefix_length < 3 && equal(*vec1++, *vec2++)) prefix_length++;`

, but when I run the line, I get an error of

`no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]`.

what is the problem with the code?

Comment: is prefix_length an object or a primitive?

Comment: @LukeB. int prefix_length

Comment: Do `str1` and `str2` have postfix ++ defined? You might need to make a SSCCE.

Comment: My bad, those are vectors not strings

Comment: @Rapptz How can I do that?

Comment: @POD, Vectors don't have increment operators defined. What would they do?

Comment: @chris Those are for going to the next element

Comment: @POD http://sscce.org/

Comment: @chris Is that only working for the string?

Comment: @POD, I'm confused. You said "they're" vectors, and now "they're" not vectors. I need more context. An SSCCE, as mentioned, would do that perfectly.

Comment: It doesn't work for either vectors or strings, it works for iterators.

Comment: @chris Those are vectors. I am trying to make my function a template. It was a string before modifying it, but now I am trying to work it out as vector too.

Comment: @zch Why did it work for strings for me then?

Comment: @POD, I don't think you and us are on the same page. It *cannot* work with strings because they have no `operator++` and no `operator*`. An SSCCE would explain everything in the clearest way.

Comment: @POD You say it works for strings? The compiler says otherwise: http://ideone.com/gUQVfv. If you want help, you're going to have to give an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You've given us one line of code that is ambiguous about types and context, and you're contradicting yourself in your answers to people's questions.

Comment: @chris My bad again, it was a char array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `vec1` and `vec2` are `vector`s, they don't have increment operators.  They're containers.  You need to use iterators to traverse them.  Something like:

```
auto it1 = vec1.cbegin(),
     it2 = vec2.cbegin();
while ( prefix_length < 3
        and it1!=vec1.cend()
        and it2!=vec2.cend()
        and equal(*it1++, *it2++) )
    ++prefix_length;
```

Comment: Something wrong with good old `&&`?  +1 for showing how iterators could be used, though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you are dealing with containers like vectors or list, then in order to traverse one element to another you need an Iterator. You can also access the elements by calling vec1.at(I++) and vec2.at(I++). Then compare the elements.